# help with the firmware file of the radio

Tags: files, filesystems, gzip, lzma

help with the firmware file of the radio. I unpack the file with the 7zip program, with the same program I can not return the file back to its original state with the same file size.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/u68D/xpEJ56GWH

Comment: Please include whatever you're trying to include in a different way. I have no idea what to do with that link, and I don't speak russian either. Edit your question and tell us in detail about your problem.

Comment: in this link a file with the extension img. this file contains pictures with GIF extension and bmp extension. using the script binwalk. binwalk -e rakunsav.img: I received a lot of files and don’t know how to put them back together